# I need to figure out how to use the facebook api breakdown:publisher_platform parameter

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Good Day,
I was wondering if you can maybe help me?
I need to figure out how to use the breakdown:publisher_platform parameter.
It does not seem to work with everything I have tried.
Here is my endpoints that I have tried, All I want to do is split my Facebook ads from Instagram ones and get them both back separately.

https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/ad_set_id/insights?publisher_platforms=facebook&date_preset=lifetime&fields=action_values,account_name,account_id,account_currency,conversion_values,conversions,cost_per_action_type,cost_per_conversion,cost_per_unique_click,frequency,estimated_ad_recallers,estimated_ad_recall_rate,engagement_rate_ranking,full_view_impressions,full_view_reach,objective,quality_ranking,reach,spend,unique_clicks,unique_ctr,date_start,date_stop,actions,ad_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,clicks,impressions,ad_id&access_token=

[https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/ad_set_id/insights?targeting={geo_locations={countries=ZA},publisher_platforms=instagram}&date_preset=lifetime&fields=action_values,account_name,account_id,account_currency,conversion_values,conversions,cost_per_action_type,cost_per_conversion,cost_per_unique_click,frequency,estimated_ad_recallers,estimated_ad_recall_rate,engagement_rate_ranking,full_view_impressions,full_view_reach,objective,quality_ranking,reach,spend,unique_clicks,unique_ctr,date_start,date_stop,actions,ad_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,clicks,impressions,ad_id&access_token=](https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/ad_set_id/insights?targeting=%7Bgeo_locations=%7Bcountries=ZA%7D,publisher_platforms=instagram%7D&date_preset=lifetime&fields=action_values,account_name,account_id,account_currency,conversion_values,conversions,cost_per_action_type,cost_per_conversion,cost_per_unique_click,frequency,estimated_ad_recallers,estimated_ad_recall_rate,engagement_rate_ranking,full_view_impressions,full_view_reach,objective,quality_ranking,reach,spend,unique_clicks,unique_ctr,date_start,date_stop,actions,ad_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,clicks,impressions,ad_id&access_token=)

https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/ad_set_id/insights?params=breakdown:publisher_platforms&date_preset=lifetime&fields=action_values,account_name,account_id,account_currency,conversion_values,conversions,cost_per_action_type,cost_per_conversion,cost_per_unique_click,frequency,estimated_ad_recallers,estimated_ad_recall_rate,engagement_rate_ranking,full_view_impressions,full_view_reach,objective,quality_ranking,reach,spend,unique_clicks,unique_ctr,date_start,date_stop,actions,ad_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,clicks,impressions,ad_id&access_token=

https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/ad_set_id?breakdown=publisher_platform&fields=id,account_id,adlabels,adset_schedule,asset_feed_id,attribution_spec,bid_adjustments,bid_amount,bid_constraints,bid_info,bid_strategy,billing_event,budget_remaining,campaign,campaign_id,configured_status,created_time,creative_sequence,daily_budget,daily_min_spend_target,daily_spend_cap,destination_type,effective_status,end_time,frequency_control_specs,instagram_actor_id,is_dynamic_creative,issues_info,learning_stage_info,lifetime_budget,lifetime_imps,lifetime_min_spend_target,lifetime_spend_cap,multi_optimization_goal_weight,name,optimization_goal,optimization_sub_event,pacing_type,promoted_object,recommendations,recurring_budget_semantics,review_feedback,rf_prediction_id,source_adset,source_adset_id,start_time,status,targeting,time_based_ad_rotation_id_blocks,time_based_ad_rotation_intervals,updated_time,use_new_app_click&access_token=

https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/ad_set_id/ads?breakdown=publisher_platform&fields=insights&publisher_platforms=instagram&access_token=

https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/ad_set_id/insights?fields=impressions&breakdown=publisher_platform&access_token=

Comment: Its unlikely you will get an answer to this, in this format.

Comment: any thoughts on how i can change it to be better?

Comment: Yeah i'm not sure, however people are greeted with a wall of blue text.

Comment: @MichaelRandall i would like to minimize it but its just all the different examples i tried to actually get the breakdown for publisher platform to work do you have any experience working with the facebook graph and marketing api ?